# Dynamically defining methods with names derived from a class attribute?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

The title might not be the best description of what I'm trying to do but I'm not sure what to call this. I came across various seemingly related concepts with names like "decorators", "descriptors", and "metaclasses" but I don't know which of those approaches (if any) I should investigate further!

Given the following classes:

```
class AnimalGreeter(object):

    def __init__(self, greeting):
        self.greeting = greeting

    def greet(self, animal):
        print(self.greeting + ", " + animal + "!")

class MyGreeter(AnimalGreeter):

    animals = ['dog', 'parrot']
```

I'd like to be able to use an instance of `MyGreeter` like this:

```
greeter = MyGreeter("What's up")
greeter.parrot
# "What's up, parrot!"
```

Effectively, I would like it to function as if I had defined `MyGreeter` like this instead:

```
class MyGreeter(AnimalGreeter):

    @property
    def dog(self):
        self.greet('dog')

    @property
    def parrot(self):
        self.greet('parrot')
```

In other words, I want to dynamically define methods (`dog()`, etc.) with names derived from an attribute (`animals`) of the class (`MyGreeter`).

What is the best way to do this?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just implement `__getattr__(self, animal)`.

Comment: Cant help here, but I'm interested in your use case. Why do you need this behavior?

Comment: @FabienP, In my case `AnimalGreeter` is a Django model and `MyGreeter` is a custom mixin that handles images with configurable filenames.  I want to have access to the image urls in Django's templates but Django's templating system does not permit passing arguments to instance methods. So I can't do the equivalent of `model.image_url('large')` in the template.  But I can access instance properties in the templates, e.g., `model.large_image_url`.

Comment: @tino: nice to know, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to do this would just be to implement `__getattr__()`, e.g.:

```
class MyGreeter(AnimalGreeter):
    animals = {'dog', 'parrot'}

    def __getattr__(self, animal):
        if animal in self.animals:
            return self.greet(animal)
        raise AttributeError("'{}' object unknown animal '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, animal))

>>> greeter = MyGreeter("What's up")
>>> greeter.parrot
What's up, parrot!
>>> greeter.cat
...
AttributeError: 'MyGreeter' object unknown animal 'cat'
```

Comment: Thanks! This was one of the suggestions I came across but was unsure if I should be concerned about overhead. `AnimalGreeter` has a lot of other attributes that are accessed frequently. Does this get executed every time I access any instance attribute?

Comment: @tino No, `__getattr__` is only called if you access an attribute that "doesn't exist", i.e. it's called when an AttributeError would be thrown. [Read the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

Comment: @Rawing, Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the link and the explanation!